# Expected string or buffer error while splitting in python

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to split a document into paragraph first and then the paragraph into lines. Then check for the lines and print the paragraph.

Although I am able to achieve that with the code below, there is some 'expected string or buffer' error that shows up when I am trying to do the same for multiple documents.

```
with io.open(input_path, mode='r') as f, io.open(write_path, mode='w') as f2:
    data = f.read()
    splat = re.split(r"\n(\s)*\n", data)
    mylist=[]
    for para1 in splat:
        splat2= re.split(r"\n", para1)
        for line1 in splat2:
           PERFORM SOME OPERATION
```

Error

```
<ipython-input-218-18e633df1d46> in custom_section(input_path, write_path)
     14         mylist=[]
     15         for para1 in splat:
---> 16             splat2= re.split(r"\n", para1)
     17             for line1 in splat2:
     18 #                 line1 = line1.decode("utf-8")

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/re.pyc in split(pattern, string, maxsplit, flags)
    169     """Split the source string by the occurrences of the pattern,
    170     returning a list containing the resulting substrings."""
--> 171     return _compile(pattern, flags).split(string, maxsplit)
    172 
    173 def findall(pattern, string, flags=0):

TypeError: expected string or buffer
```

Comment: I don't know what all caps means where you come from, but here, it's treated as the internet equivalent of screaming, and it tends to attract downvotes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this error is occurring because the list of strings returned as your variable `splat` contains one or more None objects. If you insist on using re.split() you could remove the None objects with the `filter()` function, like so: `filter(None, splat)`.

Comment: Thanks. removing none objects solved the problem.